# Is this a distance metric on connected matrix Lie groups?

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected matrix Lie group and $U \subset G$ be a ball centered at the identity $I \in G$ such that $\exp_I(.)$ is a bijection. Define $d(x,y) = \|\log(x) - \log(y)\|_F$ for $x,y \in G$, where $\|\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm. Is this a distance function? It is definitely symmetric, and I believe $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$. I'm unsure on the convexity property however.

Comment: What is $F$ and $\|\cdot\|_F$?

Comment: @ArcticChar My bad. That is the Frobenius norm, $\|A\|_F = \sqrt{\text{tr}(A^TA)}$.

Comment: *Hint*: What does this give for the obvious example(s) of 1-dimensional connected Lie groups?

Comment: @user10354138 Please correct me if I write anything wrong. 1-dim connected Lie groups are abelian and hence $\|\log(x)-\log(y)\|_F^2 = \|\log(x^{-1}y)\|_F^2$, which is in fact a distance function.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler That is not the $d(x,y)$ you wrote.

Comment: @user10354138 Edited

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $0$ in the Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ of $G$ and $U$ neighborhood $U$ of $I$ in $G$ such that
$$\exp \colon \mathcal{U}\to U$$
is a diffeo, so a bijection. Using this bijection you can transfer any distance from $\frak{U}$ to $U$. This is what you did, except: it will work in general only of a neighborhood $U$ on $I$, not on the whole $G$.